# Get hrefs from another page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I'm trying to create a function that gets a list of links from another page and pushes them into an array, but I'm stuck on what to do after the success function.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  var array = [];
    $.get('links.html',function(data) {
      //here's where I'm stuck
        $('#photo a').each(function(){
          array.push($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

links.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="photo">
    <a href="link1.html">...
    <a href="link2.html">...
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you have seems like it should work. Are you stuck on how to return it from the function? If so, you need to consider that this is an async operation, and devise a way to return the data asynchronously as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  var array = [];
    $.get('links.html',function(data) {
      //here's where I'm stuck
        $(data).find('#photo a').each(function(){
          array.push($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @gh0st Make sure to mark the answer as accepted (use the tick icon next to the answer) if so.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(data).find('#photo a')
```

You need to search for the links in the data returned by the ajax call.